# JavaFX save location of draggable nodes

Tags: javafx, drawing, drag

building a javaFX app that gets locations,width and depth of rectangles from the database in order to draw them the database contains rectangles posX, posY,width and depth according to an actual pane width and depth, i was able to draw the rectangles according to the pane i am drawing on locally, the problem is,  dont know how to update the database with the new values when a rectangle is dragged, as i should transform them back to the actual coordination, the code :

```
// resourcePosX,resourcePosY,resourceDepth and resourceWidth are the actual
// rectangle dimensions from the database
//  actualDepth and actualWidth are the actual pane dimensions
// prefWidth and prefHight are the current pane dimensions that i am drawing on 
int posX = (resourcePosX*this.prefHight)/actualDepth;
int posY = (resourcePosY*this.prefWidth)/actualWidth;

int depth = (resourceDepth*this.prefHight)/actualDepth;
int wedth = (resourceWidth*this.prefWidth)/actualWidth;

Node resource= new Rectangle(posX, posY, depth, wedth);
EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMousePressedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                orgSceneX = t.getSceneX();
                orgSceneY = t.getSceneY();
                orgTranslateX = ((Node) (t.getSource())).getTranslateX();
                orgTranslateY = ((Node) (t.getSource())).getTranslateY();
            }
        };

        EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseDraggedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                double offsetX = t.getSceneX() - orgSceneX;
                double offsetY = t.getSceneY() - orgSceneY;
                double newTranslateX = orgTranslateX + offsetX;
                double newTranslateY = orgTranslateY + offsetY;

                ((Node) (t.getSource())).setTranslateX(newTranslateX);
                ((Node) (t.getSource())).setTranslateY(newTranslateY);
            }
        };

        resource.setOnMouseDragged(onMouseDraggedEventHandler);


        resource.setOnMousePressed(onMousePressedEventHandler);
```

how to convert the rectangles current x and y to actual again ? in order to save them in the database.

---

would it be easier or better to use canvas ? as i know nothing about canvas so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `setOnMouseReleased` mousehandler and use a `fixPostion()` method which calculates the current position using the current position plus the translated position.

```
EventHandler<MouseEvent> onMouseReleasedEventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

  @Override
  public void handle(MouseEvent t) {

    fixPosition((Node) t.getSource());

  }
};

resource.setOnMouseReleased(onMouseReleasedEventHandler);

private void fixPosition( Node node) {

    double x = node.getTranslateX();
    double y = node.getTranslateY();

    node.relocate(node.getLayoutX() + x, node.getLayoutY() + y);

    node.setTranslateX(0);
    node.setTranslateY(0);

}
```

Comment: the thing is node.getLayoutX() and node.getLayoutY() are always 0 ? why is that >?

Comment: would it be better to implement using canvas ? thanks in advanced

Comment: They are 0 because you position everything using the translate methods and ignore the layoutX/Y location. In other words, the final location = [layoutX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutXProperty) + [translateX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setTranslateX-double-). imo don't use a canvas, it's more work for you. Also, I suggest you read about the [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class.